# Let $S=\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x>2\}$. Prove $\inf S = 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Okay, so I think I kind of get this one already. Since 2 is the lowest rational number in the set that's less than $x$, then $\inf S = 2$.

But is there is any other way to explain this? I feel like there's a more formal proof to it that I'm not getting. Or maybe I'm just completely wrong. Can someone help out here?

Comment: First you must show that all elements in $S$ are greater or equal to $2$(It is obvious here). Second you must prove that given any $\epsilon >0$ there is at least one element $y\in S$ such that $y<2+\epsilon $. Is that make sense?

Comment: Note that Inf is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: @Mathi Okay, so since x>2 then we already know x is greater or equal to 2. I get that so far. As for the second part, can you explain why we're trying to show that $y<2+ϵ$?

Comment: As I said before Inf is the greatest lower bound. In the first step we show that $2$ is a lower bound. In the second step we show that there is no other lower bounds for $S$ which are bigger than $2$ (To show it is the greatest).

Comment: @Mathi So, how would you go about the next step?

Comment: Given any $\epsilon >0$, consider $2$ and $2+\epsilon$. They are not equal. Since rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ we can find a rational number which lies between any two non equal real numbers. So in our case there is a rational number $y$ such that $2<y<2+\epsilon$ and hence $y\in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of $ S $, $2$ is a lower bound for $ S $. On the other hand, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $2+\epsilon $ is not a lower bound for $ S $. Indeed, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $ n\in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. So $2 + \frac{1}{n} $, an element of $ S $, is less than $2+\epsilon $. Therefore, $\inf S = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $S = 2$, we must show that $S > 2$ and $S < 2$ cannot be infima of this set.

Consider $S < 2$. Now there exists some $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $S < x < 2$, and hence we have found a greater lower bound than our $S$, this is a contradiction hence $S \not < 2$.

Consider $S > 2$, can you take it from here?